# Where to find domain name to existing EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I'm new AWS and I have to continue maintaining previous developer service that is hosted on AWS. The ec2 instance that is hosted has map to domain name of `https://****c.k**g.g***an.org.au`, however I couldn't find this domain name anywhere. I tried looking at route53, but there's no such domain name registered.

Please help, how do I find the domain name that is mapped to the EC2 instance? Where can I get that information. The reason because I want to deploy a new instance but with the same domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Masking DNS for privacy reasons.

Are you sure your DNS is hosted by Route53? Running dig against `k***.g****.org.au` has the SOA held by `ns1.mooball.net`.

The whois for `mooball.net` returns `register.com` as the owner, so I would consider reaching out to your internal teams to see who holds that account, then check your DNS delegation settings by logging in to `register.com`.

Often times the client will control their own DNS, so it would also be worth confirming with your client where their root DNS (garvan.org.au) is hosted - you can then trace the subdomain delegation to see where it is ultimately hosted.

Comment: Yeah, silly me. Apparently the DNS is managed by my own company, that's why I couldn't find it anywhere. I'm just gonna delete this question, its a silly question.

Comment: You could also leave this here for others, you wouldn't be the first to ask and then realise it may be managed elsewhere :) Either way, please mark this as an answer if  it helped you. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

check route53 service in AWS , since the domain is served by https..it could be the domain mapped to a load balancer and the load balancer has the instance...anyway you can know from the route53 there you find all the records

Comment: I have looked at route53, I couldn't find the domain under registered domain.